# AWS Amplify/AppSync/DynamoDB - Can I not do a BatchGetItem on a specified key/ secondary index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Thank you for checking out my question. My case is the following:

I am trying to query (BatchGetItem) a table by the key "clientId", which is also a secondary index. However the response of the server is `The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ..., Extended Request ID: null)`. I used [Amazon tutorial-dynamodb-batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html#single-table-batch) as example and I thought I was able to get items based on a field of choice as in [the batchgetitem-retrieve-readings example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html#batchgetitem-retrieve-readings).

My request.vtl code is:

```
#set($clientPermissions = $ctx.stash.clientPermissions)

#if( $util.isList($clientPermissions) )
  #set($ids = [])
  #foreach($item in $clientPermissions)
      #set($map = {})
      $util.qr($map.put("clientId", $util.dynamodb.toString($item.clientId)))
      $util.qr($ids.add($map))
  #end

  {
      "version" : "2018-05-29",
      "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
      "tables" : {
          "Organization-u2zvdkpmrvbovku7cnyivjcaqq-develop": {
              "keys": $util.toJson($ids),
              "consistentRead": true
          }
      }
  }
#else
  #return
#end
```

This is my table schema:

```
##
## Organizations
##
type Organization
@model(subscriptions: null)
#@auth(rules: [ { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] } ])
@key(name: "byClient", fields: ["clientId"])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  parents: [OrganizationRelation] @connection(keyName: "byChild", fields: ["id"])
  children: [OrganizationRelation] @connection(keyName: "byParent", fields: ["id"])
  clientId: ID!
  client: Client @connection(fields: ["clientId"])
}
```

Hope someone has any experience with this. I am really stuck if I can't fix this.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Jens

Comment: No idea if I'm right about this, but could it be because your mapping library is set up to refer to the key by `byClient` instead of `clientId`? So when you create your map of ids, you should do `$map.put("byId", ...)` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried you possible solution, unfortunately, that didn't work. I will try an alternative to your solution later today, hope that works 

Comment: I tried an alternative. It doesn't seem to work with a GSI